# When/Where possible vs. When/Where it is possible: is it required to use "it is"?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

Examples 1a and 1b:

- Be realistic when possible.
- Be realistic when it is possible.

Examples 2a and 2b:

- When possible, be realistic.
- When it is possible, be realistic.

Are all of these examples correct? Is there any difference between 1a and 1b, and between 2a and 2b?

Comment: None is ungrammatical; few would use the unabbreviated forms; 'whenever' and especially 'wherever' would probably be a lot more idiomatic. The variants starting 'wherever' etc would probably be more usually used.

Comment: I'd say *If sunny tomorrow we will have a picnic* is definitely "a deletion too far" for normal conversational contexts.

Comment: _If possible_ is much more idiomatic than _when possible_.

Comment: @KateBunting Edwin said that  unabbreviated forms are better. Does it mean that I should use "If possible" (abbreviated) and "When it is possible" (unabbreviated)?

Comment: Actually, Edwin said that _few (people)_ would use the unabbreviated forms, not that they were better! He suggested _wherever possible_ as an alternative.

Comment: @jsv: There is no "better" here. The shorter forms are (as usual) idiomatic, which means they're more popular and common in speech. The longer forms also occur, but less frequently, quite often simply because they're longer and English speakers talk fast. But neither one is "better".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean that in normal conversations it's more common to place dependent clause after the main one, like "We will have a picnic tomorrow, if sunny"?

Comment: I never suggested anything at all about whether the ***if-*** clause should appear ***before*** or ***after*** the dependent clause (that's just a stylistic choice, and neither position is inherently better or worse). All I meant was that in my specific cited example, it's "excessive" in real *spoken* contexts to delete the highlighted subject & verb: *If **it is** sunny tomorrow we will have a picnic*.